# Php unclear definition of $use_include_path in file_get_contents

Tags: php

As I was looking on http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php for the `file_get_contents` function, I noticed that it takes an optional second parameter named `$use_include_path` but I cannot understand what is the use and how changes the `file_get_contents` behavior.

Can you provide me an example in order to understand it better?

Comment: for ex:file_put_contents("D:/bharathi.txt","\n RATING REVIEW \n".print_r($result,true),FILE_APPEND);     when you run likethis  it will store your particular variable results in d folder with the name of bharathi.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, I have file `/tmp/code.txt` and I need to get contents of this file, I can write something like:

```
var_dump(file_get_contents('code.txt'));
```

but it will fall with error (`No such file or directory`), hence I have to profile full path to file, but in case I don't want to do it, I can write something like:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/tmp/');
var_dump(file_get_contents('code.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH));
```

and it will work!

It is very useful in case you have library or sub-project or you mount your sub-project into another project or you have SDK or something else...

and you can have `set_include_path` in your bootstrap script for your module/library/whatever but in your code, you have only clear usage of particular files without full path, only relative...

Answer (score 4):

`include_path` in PHP is similar to `PATH` env variable in the OS: it defines a set of directories where to look for an included/read file.

By default, it is `.:/usr/share/php` which means current directory `.` and `/usr/share/php`. The semicolon `:` serves as a separator in UNIX-like environments. The separator for your environment is specified in a `PATH_SEPARATOR` constant.

So, by calling `file_get_contents` with a relative path and the second parameter as `true`, PHP would look from the current directory first and then, when specified file is not found, from `/usr/share/php`.

You can set any set of paths to the include_path by calling [set_include_path](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) function. It is good to retain former `include_path` so you won't break things for your setup:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/<your custompath>');
```